# Method class in Java

Tags: java, class

I am currently working on a project where I found this syntax:

```
Method m = bluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
```

What is the purpose of "Method" class in Java and why we use it? Please elaborate with an example
Thanks in advance!

PS: I already saw the Java docs but not able to understand it.

Comment: You need to read understand why and when reflections will be used.

Comment: This is part of Reflection. I suggest you to read [Trail: The Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Comment: It is a kind of reflection.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks man! I will surely check this.

Comment: This question makes no sense. What have you tried? Have you gone through the documentation first? It is clearly mentioned there.

Comment: @stalin I tried and as I accepted that I was unaware about the reflection so I didn't understand it. But what I did so wrong that it gets too much of downvote.

Comment: and as I clearly mentioned when I found this syntax I didn't understand the usage and after reading doc and searching on net I thought I should ask here on SO but I guess I made a  big mistake....btw thanks for suggesting Reflection now it is cleared.

Comment: btw, this: `(CLass[]) null` hints to severe brain damage.

Comment: @JackSparrow a friend of my dad's developed a great program that illustrates a proper use of reflection. I then went on to create my one on the side, but on an offline and open-source way. You can check out his program at [codingbat.com](http://codingbat.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Method class is part of the "reflection" API which is about meta-programming. That means you can deal with structures of your program as data and process it in a java program. This allows flexible generic or abstract solutions. Method itself just represents a method in a Java class. There are other classes representing other parts of Java programs, too (e.g. `Class`).